# Como faço validação de elemento (button) não presente mais na tela (era apresentado, mas não é mais) - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

alguém pode me ajudar?

Como faço validação de elemento (button) não presente mais na tela?
Ele era apresentado. Fiz o click e o button sumiu (cenário já esperado). No entanto, desejo validar/confirmar que o button não existe mais na tela. Como procedo?

O botão é localizado por id "btn-two".

Utilizando Selenium WebDriver - Java.

Comment: Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Olá, Estvao FPM! Por favor, poste seu código, assim ficará mais fácil te alguém ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso pode te ajudar:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("btn-two")));
```

Pensando nisso, só pra ter uma comparação pois não tenho o projeto em Java, tem um exemplo do WebdriverIO (JavaScript) que utilizo em meus projetos. Ele inverte a validação do `wait`:

```
$(selector).waitForExist(ms, reverse, error)
```

Nesse caso o parâmetro `reverse` por padrão vem como `false`, esperando pelo seletor. Caso seja `true`, ele espera que o seletor não traga nenhum elemento.

**Fonte** - https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/waitForExist.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this :

assertFalse(driver.findelements(By.cssSelector("#btn-two")).size() == 0);

Comment: But that link do answer that question

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]! O idioma do site é português, então por favor traduza a resposta (talvez vc tenha confundindo com o [Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/), mas enfim...) Também seria interessante incluir alguma explicação do seu código, pois respostas que têm somente código [não são o ideal](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7172/112052).